# reactjs setState before render on update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component and the requirement is to setState before render on update (url hash change). Below is code snippet:

```
componentConfig: function() {
   .....
   this.setState({rows: rows});  
   this.setState({loadMoreBtn: loadMoreIsVisible})
},
```

I was it working before, I was calling this method from `getInitialState` and it was working fine. `getInitialState` fires only once so I was not able to update it on url change. I tried various other inbuilt update methods such as `componentWillReceiveProps` but they are one step behind. Seems like render happens before this method gets called. I also tried to call it from `render` but obviously states get confused and it breaks.

[image]

As this image demonstrates, `componentRillReceiveProps` always behind render. I need something that fires before render each time on url update. Hope it makes sense.

or in other words, I would like to fire `getInitialState` on hash change.

```
   var React = require('react'),
    projectsData = require('./../projects'),
    ProjectsRow = require('./projects_row'),
    itemsInRow = 3,
    noOfDefaultRows = 2,
    projects = [],
    currentProjects = [],
    currentPageRows,
    currentParamKey;

var Projects = React.createClass({

    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.componentConfig(this.props);
    }, 

    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
        this.componentConfig(nextProps);
    },

    componentConfig: function(props) {
        var rows = [],
            currentParamKey = 'projects',
            loadMoreIsVisible = true,
            i; 

        if(props.params.key) {
            currentParamKey = props.params.key;
        }   

        projects = projectsData.getByKey(currentParamKey);      
        projectsData.currentState[currentParamKey] = noOfDefaultRows;       
        currentProjects = projects.slice(); //Create a copy or array 
        noOfDefaultRows = projectsData.currentState[currentParamKey] || noOfDefaultRows;    

        for (i = 0; i < noOfDefaultRows; i++) {
            if(currentProjects.length) {
                rows.push(currentProjects.splice(0, itemsInRow));
            } 
        }  

        currentProjects.length ? loadMoreIsVisible = true : loadMoreIsVisible = false;

        this.setState({rows: rows});  
        this.setState({loadMoreBtn: loadMoreIsVisible})

        console.log('Finished executing componentConfig and currentParamKey = ' ,currentParamKey);
    },

    loadMoreProjects: function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var addRow = this.state.rows;

        if(currentProjects.length) {
            currentPageRows++;
            addRow.push(currentProjects.splice(0, itemsInRow));
            this.setState({rows: addRow});  
        } 

        if(!currentProjects.length) {
            this.setState({loadMoreBtn: false})
        }   
    },

    render: function() {

        console.log('Now in render and currentParamKey = ' ,currentParamKey);

        var projectUrl;

        //currentParamKey = this.props.params.key;

        if(currentParamKey === 'projects') {
            projectUrl = '#/project';
        } else {
            projectUrl = '#/project/' + currentParamKey
        }   

        return (
            < div className="projects">
                < div className = "jumbotron" >
                    < div className = "container" >
                        < h1 > Projects < /h1> 
                    < /div> 
                < /div>

                < div className = "container" >

                    {this.state.rows.map(function(row, i) {
                        return <ProjectsRow url={projectUrl} row={row} key={i} />
                    }.bind(this))}

                < /div> 

                < div className = "container text-center" > 
                    <a id="loadMore" className= {this.state.loadMoreBtn ? 'linkStyle1' : 'hide'} 
                        onClick = {this.loadMoreProjects}
                        role="button" > <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i><span>Load More Projects</span> 
                    </a>
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <div className="contact-me-link">
                        <a className="linkStyle1" href="#/contact">
                            <i className="fa fa-angle-right"></i><span>Contact</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            < /div>
        );  
    }
});

module.exports = Projects;
```

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps should run before the next render cycle. Could you post a bit more code to give us a better idea of what you are doing?

Comment: Did you notice that componentWillReceiveProps will give the new state as an argument, so it's only this.state that is one step behind?

Comment: @Seppo420, it takes an array of projects depending on url. So if I go to /xml and then /html. /html will contain /xml projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The componentWillReceiveProps get new props as a parameter. The old props remain unchanged on this method execution, so you need to initialize your state based on this parameter. Try passing the props as a parameter to your componentConfig method:

```
componentWillMount: function() {
    this.componentConfig(this.props);
}, 
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
    this.componentConfig(nextProps);
},
componentConfig: function(data) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Almost working but I have an issue and I would like to understand it. currentParamKey is undefined in render. Any idea why? Code updated

Comment: It seems that you are redefining it in the componentConfig method, it is declared with 'var' there. So, your global currentParamKey remains undefined. Assign a value to it on the separate line without var statement